# There is not enough space on the disk when there is?

Tags: windows, filesystems, network-shares

Permissions are fine (inherited) and checking effective permissions everything is AOK.

[image]

As you can see i can make a file in the docs folder but not the pdf_docs subfolder.

[image]

The folder has a lot of files and is quite large- i wonder if i've reached a limit? I couldn't find anything on google.

```
Size: 51.0 GB (54,819,804,885 bytes)
Size on disk: 52.0 GB (55,925,719,040)
Contains 554,697 Files
```

**EDIT** I've just checked and i can delete files... and for every file i delete i appear to be able to create a new one. This definitely points toward a limit in terms of number of files?

[image]

Comment: Time for a `chkdsk`

Comment: It seems to be a network drive. You should check the disk on which the actual data is located, not the properties of your locally mapped drive.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg you're right, I'd have a look at quotas first then permissions.

Comment: permissions, space and quota aok on the drive. as mentioned the parent folder is AOK and part of the same volume with inherited permissions. i have just added a screenshot that shows if i delete 1 file i can create 1 file... definitely seems to be linked to the number of files?

Comment: does it behave differently if you are working on the server itself, rather than over a file share?

Comment: FWIW, this guy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780735/looking-for-an-efficient-way-to-check-for-file-existence-on-windows-with-files-o) says he has millions of files per directory, so I don't think you're hitting a hard limit.

Comment: Another useful test would be to see whether you can append to an existing file or not.

Comment: Is there a significant delay before you get the failure message? Perhaps this is a case of something timing out.

Comment: Perhaps its an MFT issue?

Comment: Is this a network drive?  And if so, is it DFS?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a Windows client trying to access a Linux server. I shared a folder that had mounts from different disks. The problem and solution are described in this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/631977/535528

in short the solution is to share the individual disks, rather than some parent where those are mounted. This will also result in exporting multiple shares instead of one from the samba configuration.

Comment: This not an answer to the question. The OP ask about Windows, not Linux

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: looks to me like it would still apply to a Windows client accessing a Linux server, the OP never clarified whether it was a network drive or not.

Comment: the 2nd screenshot (properties) shows a path starting with "\\", so it is a network drive.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that a quota has been set on the pdf_docs directory.

Directory quotas are configured using the File Server Resource Manager tool.  You must be an administrator on the file server to use it.

Comment: there is no quota on the folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your permissions are indeed correct, and that the drive has sufficient storage space to create the file, I would check the number of characters in the full path to that folder. The maximum length for the path in Windows is 260 characters according to [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265782/438273).

Comment: definitely not the problem as there are plenty of files in the folder and it has been working flawlessly up till now

Comment: @LeeTickett So you did double-checked permissions, and actual storage space?

Comment: yes- my screenshot even shows me able to create a file in the parent folder but not the subfolder

Comment: If the file server is a linux or other unix-y machine running SAMBA, you could conceivably be hitting an inode limit on a poorly configured partition.  That partition would have to be different for the sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to this image:

[image]

It looks like it's set to Read-Only. I think that any be your problem. If you deselect it probably will be fixed. If it isn't, it's something more serious.

Comment: In case you're wondering why anyone can change your answer (like I did), check [this](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/edit) page. By the way, **anyone** (including you) can edit anybody's post but it will be [reviewed](http://puu.sh/7Hhcw.png) by anyone with 2,000 rep or more (such as myself).

Comment: If you read the whole question and look at the screenshots you'll see that deleting a file then allows me to add a new one- so that definitely isn't the issue.

Comment: The "read-only" flag prevents a directory from being deleted, but does not prevent files from being written to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows a directory is implemented as an index file, and when an index file gets too fragmented it is not possible to add new entries.

To resolve the problem, defragment the index file [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291292/886887).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem or not, but I was struggling for a while with the same issue. I bought a new external hard disk 6TB WD, while copying a large folder with too many folders and files, the same issue occurs. The hard disk was formatted in exFAT file extension, reformatting it to NTFS solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It just took me a month to figure out the same problem. My system saw only 1GB free out of 8GB of my SD Card on my PI, when i tried to mount Samsung 128GB. The reason was simple, I had files in the mounting directories (left over from previous sharing.) Once i removed everything from the folders, I got full 119GB free to use in Win10. :)
I hope this will help somebody in a future.